# Docker - npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/package.json' ----- /docker-entrypoint.sh: 38: exec: npm: not found

Tags: reactjs, docker, npm

I've got the following Dockerfile for a React app and I'm running tests after I build this container. This is my first day with Docker and I'm following a course, so not really sure what I'm doing.

```
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine as builder

WORKDIR '/app'
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y npm
ARG NODE_VERSION=14
RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_${NODE_VERSION}.x | bash - \
  && apt-get update \
  && apt-get autoremove \
  && apt-get install -y nodejs

COPY --from=builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

The reason I have these two `RUN` after `FROM nginx` is that after  running `docker build -t username/project-name .`, I'd run `docker run ID npm run test` and get `/docker-entrypoint.sh: 38: exec: npm: not found`.

Since I added the two `RUN` statements (which I'm not sure is a good idea) the build is still successful, but then I run the tests with `docker run ID npm run test` and I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
```

I've also tried running `docker run -w /app ID npm run test` but get the `ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/package.json'` error.

My file structure is this:

```
project
  node_modules
  src
  Dockerfile
  package.json
  ...
```

Comment: why would docker open `/package.json` since the path is `/app/package.json`

Comment: WORKDIR is not defined in your 2nd build stage.

Comment: so I should define the WORKDIR as the current dir. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an multi-stage build.

`docker build -t username/project-name .` creates a container from the last stage starting with `from nginx`. In this container you copy the build directory but no package.json.

To solve this problem you could do the following

1. Run the test in the docker build in container `builder`. To do this add in the Dockerfile the following line `RUN npm run test`
2. Create the `builder` container with `docker build --target=builder -t username/project-name` and use `docker run ID npm run test`
3. Copy all sources and project data to your last stage, but this is not recommended

Comment: How exactly would one go for doing these 3 steps?

Comment: You can solve your issue with each of this points. What solution do you prefer?

Comment: Could you help me with option 2?

Comment: I updated my answer. I hope this will help you

Comment: it indeed worked, thanks! Can I also ask for option 1? I think I just found out the point of the course I'm taking is to deploy this to AWS with a Travis CI thing in between so I might need to change something on the Dockerfile?

Comment: Ok i updatet also this point. Can you please accept my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The overall multi-stage build pattern you show here is typical for producing a deployable image with a browser-based application compiled down to static files.  The entire contents of the image are the last stage, starting from the final `FROM` line:

```sh
FROM nginx
# You would not typically reinstall Node here
# Only copy in the prebuilt files
COPY --from=builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
# EXPOSE, CMD, etc. from base nginx image
```

So this image *only* contains the contents of the `./build` tree from the first stage and nothing else.  The `package.json` file and the `node_modules` tree aren't part of this.

There's no rule that you must use exclusively Docker-based tools, even if you're eventually shipping a Docker image.  For day-to-day development I'd recommend using a host-based Node environment, rather than trying to indirectly use Docker to simulate it.  Then you can run your unit tests before you package up your application.

```sh
# Work on code
$EDITOR src/main.js
# Run tests (without involving Docker)
npm run test
# Run a local (non-Docker) dev server and make sure it works
npm run start
# It works?  Build a minimal nginx-based Docker image and ship it
docker build -t my/frontend-app:20210511 .
docker run -p 8888:80 my/frontend-app:20210511
docker push my/frontend-app:20210511
```

Comment: the reason I'm reinstalling node is the following: I'm able to build the image, but when I try to run a test with `docker run ID npm run test` I get `/docker-entrypoint.sh: 38: exec: npm: not found` as an error. I'd be happy to move one step back and find out why that error is happening. Also, I didn't really understand if I your 2nd block of code should be pasted on the Dockerfile.

Comment: I'm suggesting not running tests in Docker at all.  The last block of code is something you'd type into your shell on the host system.